# How can I capture 401 errors in asp.net core?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, .net-core, http-status-codes

In my startup I have added this code:

```
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error", "?statusCode={0}");
            app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();
```

In my controller I have added:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Error(int? statusCode = null)
    {

        return View(new ErrorViewModel { 
                                         RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ??
                                           HttpContext.TraceIdentifier, 
                                             StatusCode = statusCode
                                        });
    }
```

And I also have this middleware class for catching 500's:

```
public class ExceptionHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ExceptionHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        }
    }
}
```

I can catch 404's and 500. Everything else comes back as 404 (including 401).
If I debug, the statusCode in the Error action is always 404.

How can I get the statusCode to reflect the reality (i.e. 401)?

Answer (score 1):

You can check my code [here](https://github.com/Awesome-CMS-Core/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/Extension/ApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs#L46-L83) .It's global handle exception so you can catch 401 exception but I think you need to throw error code in order for global handler exception catch 401 error code

Comment: Thanks, could explain how each part of the highlighted code is working to handle 404 / 500 / 401 errors?